# How to remove duplicate emails csv file

Tags: php, email, csv, duplicates

I need your help,

How to remove duplicate email address in csv file

example:
i have 10000 emails records (all-email.csv)
after sent out the email promotion then i receive 2550 invalid email (invalid.csv)

actualy the 2550 emails is come from my 10000 emails. (all-email.csv)

i want to use all record emails become a source and to find any duplicate email from invalid email then only save the clean email (no duplicate) into clean email (clean-email.csv)

which means (10000 email - 2550 email = 7450 clean email)

I would greatly appreciate if you able to help me, thanks

this is my php code:

```
    <?php
$all = file('clean1.csv');
$invalid = file('Bounced_Email.csv');
$correctEmails=array_diff($all, $invalid); 

//print_r($correctEmails)."\n";
foreach ($correctEmails as $email) { echo $email."<br>"; }
?>
```

i'm so tired keep on trying on this

Comment: `$array` and `$array2` aren't fed inside your function, they're out of scope, and why not try array functions like `array_diff`. are you sure about using `file()` not `filegetcsv`?

Comment: Try to store all those emails in DB and delete with join. Creating such a big array and iterating it... Well, maybe if it's not that frequent using arrays is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i try use your method to run the php code : $all = file('all_email.csv'); $invalid = file('invalid_email.csv'); $correctEmails=array_diff($all, $invalid); for ($i=0; $i < count($all, $invalid); $i = $i++) { echo $correctEmails[$i]."<br>"; } but still error, any solution...

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff` is for such purposes. Simply try:

```
$all = file('all_email.csv');
$invalid = file('invalid_email.csv');
$correctEmails=array_diff($all, $invalid);
```

> array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Thank you for your help, 
i try use your method to run the php code :

$all = file('all_email.csv');
$invalid = file('invalid_email.csv');
$correctEmails=array_diff($all, $invalid);

for ($i=0; $i < count($all, $invalid); $i = $i++) { 
    echo $correctEmails[$i]."<br>";
}

but still error, any solution... thanks

Comment: @user2446399 - What kind of error? BTW: try to echo your `$correctEmails` in code like this: `foreach ($correctEmails as $email) { echo $email."<br>";  }`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now is work likes what I want...

if we want to count how many email duplicate (already deleted) between (File_A.csv and File_B.csv). do you know any idea to make it work ?

Comment: Yes, for count how many are in both array, you can use `array_intersect($all,$invalid)` - this function returns values which are in **both** arrays.- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php